# Python store non numeric string as number

Tags: python

I am currently trying to find a way to convert any sort of text to a number, so that it can later be converted back to text.
So something like this:

```
text = "some string"
number = somefunction(text)

text = someotherfunction(number)
print(text) #output "some string"
```

Comment: And your question is...? and your own trials consisted in...?

Comment: What are you doing with this number? What's the point of this? If the string can be long, you'll need to have really large numbers, since the number needs as many bits as the original number of bits in the string.

Comment: @MASL My question is if there is such a thing, i tried ascii values but those only worked for individual letters. Besides I could not find anything on google since every result gave me the question of how to turn numeric strings into integers.

Comment: @Barmar I want to create a little encryption programme and for that i need the string as a number to perform calculations, but I also need to be able to convert the number back to the original string.

Comment: Operate on the individual characters, not the whole string.

Comment: Is there a limit on the number of characters in the strings you want to convert to numbers?

Comment: The string can definately have a limit. It doesn't have to be a long piece of text. Say max 100 chars or so.

Comment: To change 100 characters into a number, you need to have a number with almost 300 digits. That's assuming just 8-bit characters. When you extent to Unicode, you'll need over 1,000 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ASCII values to do this:

ASCII to int:

```
ord('a')  # = 97
```

Back to a string:

```
str(unichr(97))  # = 'a'
```

From there you could iterate over the string one character at a time and store these in another string. Assuming you are using standard ASCII characters, you would need to zero pad the numbers (because some are two digits and some three) like so:

```
s = 'My string'
number_string = ''

for c in s:
    number_string += str(ord(c)).zfill(3)
```

To decode this, you will read the new string three characters at a time and decode them into a new string.

This assumes a few things:

- all characters can be represented by ASCII (you could use Unicode code points if not)
- you are storing the numeric value *as a string*, not as an actual int type (not a big deal in Python—saves you from having to deal with maximum values for int on different systems)
- you absolutely *must* have a numeric value, i.e. some kind of hexadecimal representation (which could be converted into an int) and cryptographic algorithms won't work
- we're not talking about GB+ of text that needs to be converted in this manner

Comment: That will work for a single character, how do you extend it to a long string?

Comment: I was hoping the OP understood how to iterate a string at least, but added a good example for good measure

Comment: He wants a single number, not a list. After all, a string is just an array of character codes internally.

Comment: Since i need to do calculations on the number I would prefer a method where a single number can be returned, since otherwise i would have to store extra data for converting the number back into the original list

Comment: Thanks I didn't know there was such a thing as zfill. I'll leave the question open for a little bit and if nothing else comes in i'll accept your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @SjoerdvdBelt you could at least upvote it if it's helpful... (but if it doesn't meet your requirements, explain why)

Comment: I was actually initially hoping there would be a function designed for this purpose, so I thought I might wait a few minutes see if anything pops up, but maybe im just being picky since this does solve my problem. I will upvote and accept it.

Comment: You can use `string.maketrans` to assign your own int value to each number also. Then just use `string.translate("my string", my_translation)`

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Python 3, it's pretty easy. First, convert the `str` to `bytes` in a chosen encoding (`utf-8` is usually appropriate), then use `int.from_bytes` to convert to an `int`:

```
number = int.from_bytes(mystring.encode('utf-8'), 'little')
```

Converting back is slightly trickier (and will lose trailing `NUL` bytes unless you've stored how long the resulting string should be somewhere else; if you switch to `'big'` endianness, you lose leading `NUL` bytes instead of trailing):

```
recoveredstring = number.to_bytes((number.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'little').decode('utf-8')
```

You can do something similar in Python 2, but it's less efficient/direct:

```
import binascii
number = int(binascii.hexlify(mystring.encode('utf-8')), 16)

hx = '%x' % number
hx = hx.zfill(len(hx) + (len(hx) & 1))  # Make even length hex nibbles
recoveredstring = binascii.unhexlify(hx).decode('utf-8')
```

That's equivalent to the `'big'` endian approach in Python 3; reversing the intermediate bytes as you go in each direction would get the `'little'` effect.